# Admob Interstitial - Back Button Crashes App

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have integrated admob interstitial ads into my app. Everything works fine except that when the ad appears, if the user clicks on the ad and then presses the phones 'back' button, the app crashes and quits.

I believe this is a known bug in the Admob SDK but I was wondering if anyone has a workaround for this problem?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Google AdMobs are no longer supported for windows phone apps. They had launched AdMobs in Beta phase and the ads often caused crashes when clicked. They no longer support apps on windows phone platform. Heres a screenshot of my dashboard with a notification from AdMobs where they have mentioned that WP apps wont be supported after 30th September 2013.

Comment: Hi Vivek - what is your source for this information? I still see the SDK available for download on the AdMob site and no mention of dropping support. If so, whats a good alternative?

Comment: the comment doesnt allow me to attach an image so i have added it in the answer itself. its a screen shot of my dashboard. As you can see, they deprecated support after 30th Sept 2013. Also my account isnt showing a SDK available for download.

Comment: Hi Vivek, I cant tell from the screenshot but are your apps for 'Windows Phone 7' devices, if so you may be correct but I believe Windows Phone 8 devices are still supported. For instance Admob is still actively taking bugs and announcing 'upcoming fixes'. Here is an example from a few weeks ago: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/hF1STMFqEZI

Comment: Also, you may be referring to the older, legacy Admob site. Around that time  Ihad to migrate all my apps to the newer Admob site. I have several WP apps and don't see that notification.